# Using the windows/super/Meta key in Fedora

Tags: keyboard, eee-pc, fedora-14

I use Fedora 14 on an Asus EEE PC 1015P and I want to use the windows key to trigger the panels main menu (default setting = ALT + F1). The problem is that the keyboard shortcut dialog doesn't recognize the windows key when I press it. Any Ideas?

Comment: In *nix distributions, they like to refer to it as the `Super` or `Meta` key.

Comment: I know, thats not the problem, on the keyboard shortcut menu, you have to press the keys you want to link and the window/super/meta key is not recognized.

Comment: Isn't Alt the default meta key?

Comment: You may be right with this, I'm not sure. Anyway, I want to use the windows key, independent of what it is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute the command:

`gconf-editor`

and navigate to the option:

`/apps/metacity/global_keybindings/panel_main_menu`

and check it's value. That key-combination is the *key* for the panel's main menu.

If you want, you can change it to your desired combination.

Comment: This seems to be the right way, unfortunately the command gconf-editor does nothing "Program not found...". Are you sure this works in fedora 14? I also tried "conf" and "gconf" with the same results.

Comment: YES. The command is correct. I checked it on debian. And  I am pretty much sure that, it will work on fedora 14 too. Please check the rpm for this binary. For debian, name of deb is `gconf-editor`

Comment: I installed the gconf-editor and found the option. After some trial and error I found that the win key is mapped as "Mod4". Unfortunately its not possible to use this key without combining it with another. Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: No way. You can use only the super key to desired one. On my machine, I mapped that to Alt+F2 ( Run Dialog ). Value is `Super_L`

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer, the bounty is yours. I only have to wait for the time limit (2 hours left) to reward your affort.